# Is there a way to catch notification PendingIntent?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

As title says - Is there a way to catch notification PendingIntent?

I want to trigger `markNotification(id)` from single spot in my application to avoid repetition. But I am unable to find a way to catch `PendingIntent` that is triggering my `Activity`. Maybe there is a way to do it some other way than catching `PendingIntent`?

**Context**

I've added schemes to my `Activity` and I have working `FirebaseMessagingService` which is responsible for creating my `Notification` and its triggers. My `PendingIntent` is holding `Intent` with `URI` that will trigger required `Activity`.

Comment: you mean `NotificationListenerService` ?

Comment: Sorry for the earlier answer. I misunderstand your question. Still I have no clue

Comment: @pskink it is listening add/remove/change of Notification not its click events.

Comment: @pskink I did little more digging and it could have worked BUT it requires API 18+ and I'm working on API 16+ :C

Comment: too bad as there is no "support lib" replacement, there is only `NotificationCompatSideChannelService`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to resolve my dillema.

I've added to my `PendingIntent` class via `intent.setClass()` to forward it to my custom `BroadcastReceiver`. Then in this receiver I trigger my method responsible for marking the notification in the database. And finnaly I trigger `startActivity()` with my original intent that will start specific `Activity` with `URI` held inside `intent.getData()`.